# FASTest > mysql get last distinct records return all columns

Tags: mysql, performance, max, distinct

```
idx info    market  po  side    odd     unique_odd
10  927606  OU_OT   2.5 under   2.01    927606_OU_2.5_under
11  927606  OU_OT   2.5 under   2.02    927606_OU_2.5_under
12  927606  OU_OT   2.5 over    1.81    927606_OU_2.5_over
13  927776  OU_OT   3.5 under   1.67    927776_OU_3.5_under
14  927776  OU_OT   3.5 over    2.11    927776_OU_3.5_over
15  927776  OU_OT   3.5 over    2.31    927776_OU_3.5_over
```

odds_etc DATABASE is here.

I want to output like these.

```
11  927606  OU_OT   2.5 under   2.02    927606_OU_2.5_under
12  927606  OU_OT   2.5 over    1.81    927606_OU_2.5_over
13  927776  OU_OT   3.5 under   1.67    927776_OU_3.5_under
15  927776  OU_OT   3.5 over    2.31    927776_OU_3.5_over
```

This means distinct for unique_odd and MAX(idx)
It could below sql, but it takes 7sec. it is too long, i want 1~2sec.

```
SELECT T1.* FROM odds_etc T1
INNER JOIN (SELECT unique_odd,MAX(idx) as maxidx FROM odds_etc GROUP BY unique_odd) groupT2
ON T1.unique_odd = groupT2.unique_odd AND T1.idx = groupT2.maxidx 
WHERE info='$info'
```

Answer (score 0):

With an index on `odds_etc(unique_odd, idx)`, the following query might have better performance:

```
select oe.*
from odds_etc oe
where info = '$info' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from odds_etc oe2
                  where oe2.unique_odd = oe.unique_odd and
                        oe2.idx > oe.idx
                 );
```

This phrases the query as:  "Get me all rows where the `unique_odd` has no greater value of `idx`."  That is a more complicated way of saying:  "Get me the row with the maximum `idx` for each `unique_odd`."  But this version can take advantage of the above index, which should improve performance.

You probably also want an index on `odds_etc(info, unique_odd, idx)` as well.

EDIT:

For performance, you need the following two indexes:

```
create index idx_odds_etc_unique_odd_idx on odds_etc(unique_odd, idx);
create index idx_odds_etc_info_unique_odd_idx on odds_etc(info, unique_odd, idx);
```

Comment: $sql = "SELECT  * 
 FROM  odds_etc T1 where idx = ( SELECT MAX(idx) from odds_etc T2 WHERE T1.unique_odd = T2.unique_odd ) "; I tried this too and it takes 1min too.

Comment: @user3734604 . . . That is with both indexes?

Comment: @user3734604 . . . Did you create the two indexes specified in the answer?  They are important for performance.